# 403 Forbiddenh in Client's Server

Tags: php, ajax, httpforbiddenhandler

In my application when i sending mail forbodden error message is displayed
This is my ajax code

```
$.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",  
                    url: "http://www.ryuneo-clients.co.uk/houndzabout/process.php/"+x+"/"+y,
                    success: function(msg){
                    if(msg == 0)
                    {
                        alert("Your Request Is Send!");
                    }else{
                        alert("Your Request Is Failed!");
                    }
                    $("#txtname").val("Your Name");
                    $("#txtphone").val("Your Phone Number");
                    }
                });
```

This is the process.php page

```
<?php
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $pieces = explode("/", $uri);
    $name = $pieces[3];
    $phone = $pieces[4];

    $nam11 =  urldecode($name);

    /*$to = "mariyadavis90@gmail.com";*/
    $to = "wirralpetnanny@live.co.uk";
    $subject = "New Request Come !";
    $message = '<div style="background-color: #EEEEEE;border-bottom: 1px solid #DCDCDC;padding: 10px 0 20px;width: 400px;"> 
<div style="width:400px;">

<div style="width:400px;background-color:#eeeeee;padding: 10px 0 20px;border-bottom:1px solid #dcdcdc;">
<div style="width:300px; text-align:center;color:#666666;margin-left:20px;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;">
Now you got a new request from :
</div>
</div> <!--end of div_form_main-->
<div style="width:400px;background-color:#eeeeee;padding: 10px 0 20px;border-bottom:1px solid #dcdcdc;">
<div style="float:left;width:150px;color:#666666;margin-left:20px;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;"> Name:</div>
<div style="float:left;width:auto;color:#000000;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;">'.$nam11.'</div>
</div> <!--end of div_form_main-->
<!--end of div_form_main-->
<div style="width:400px;background-color:#eeeeee;padding: 10px 0 20px;border-bottom:1px solid #dcdcdc;">
<div style="float:left;width:150px;color:#666666;margin-left:20px;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;"> Phone Number:</div>
<div style="float:left;width:auto;color:#000000;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;">'.$phone.'</div></div> <!--end of div_form_main-->
</div> <!--end of div_password_main-->';
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";
    if(!mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
    {
        echo 1;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 0;
    }
    //die();
?>
```

when i sending mail

```
"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://www.ryuneo-clients.co.uk/houndzabout/process.php/fvgh/111-111-11111111"
```

is displayed in firebug.When i taking the url in new window this message come

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /houndzabout/process.php/fvgh/111-111-11111111 on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a .htaccess file specifying rewrite rules, your linux server will interpret that as a path.  So instead of looking for

file process.php in folder .../houndzabout and passing it "fvgh" and "111-111-11111111"

The server is looking for

file 111-111-11111111 in folder .../hound/process.php/fvgh and passing it nothing

(note that folder names with periods are valid)

It's doing this because you're separating your filename (houndzabout/process.php) and arguments with a forward slash.

Traditionally, "GET" parameters are passed following a question mark (?) and separated by ampersands (&).

In that case, your url line in your javascript should look something like:

```
url: "http://www.ryuneo-clients.co.uk/houndzabout/process.php?"+x+"&"+y
```

Comment: but when iam using this code url: "http://www.ryuneo-clients.co.uk/houndzabout/process.php?"+x+"&"+y .The result ias same as above

Comment: You may get the same error type (forbidden / 403), but the error message will certainly be different.  Update your post with the new error message if you can.

Comment: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /houndzabout/process.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.  Tj=his is the error

Comment: So not you have it looking for the correct file, but for some reason you're not able to access it.  Its likely that (a) the file or directory is missing or not uploaded to the webserver, (b) the path is mistyped / you have a typo, or (c) your folder permissions are set incorrectly.  Ensure that (a) and (b) are not the case.